# Trying to trigger pop-up works locally but not in GitLab, giving org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Browsing context has been discarded

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, gauge

I am testing a pop-up which is triggered by moving the cursor out of page content in any way (including switching tabs etc).

Locally I have tried switching tabs, moving cursor by offset, clicking on the URL, they all work locally but my test fails in GitLab.

One of the errors I got when trying to click by offset was:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Browsing context has been discarded
Build info: version: '3.141.59'
java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 85.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20210118153634, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.29.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 75, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofileTi9Klr, moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.19.0-13-amd64, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: a30a1170-c58e-4aa5-8e2d-5dd...}
Session ID: a30a1170-c58e-4aa5-8e2d-5dd1e56d192e
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=header}
```

I cannot figure out what to do to trigger the pop-up in gitlab without breaking the browser. It doesn't work with Chrome either.

Comment: did you take screenshot and checked if it is actually opening the pop up . IF not it might be issue with the environment

Comment: Hello @PDHide it is not opening the pop-up as seen from the screenshot